# Elasticsearch Sorting Tiebreakers

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I am creating a search engine for a photo sharing social network and the documents of the site have the following schema

```
{
    "id": 123456
    "name": "Foo",
    "num_followers": 123456,
    "num_photos": 123456
}
```

I would like my search results to satisfy the following requirements:

- Only have results where the search query strings matches the "name" field in the document
- Rank the search results by number of followers descending
- In the case where multiple customers have the same number of followers, rank by number of photos descending

For example, say I have the following documents in my index:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 3,
    "num_photos": 27
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 25,
    "num_photos": 1
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 8,
    "num_photos": 2
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 8,
    "num_photos": 5
}
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "FooBar",
    "num_followers": 10000,
    "num_photos": 20000
}
```

If I search "Customer" in the search bar of the site, the ES hits should be in the following order:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 25,
    "num_photos": 1
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 8,
    "num_photos": 5
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 8,
    "num_photos": 2
}
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Customer",
    "num_followers": 3,
    "num_photos": 27
}
```

I'm assuming I will need to perform some sort of compact query to create this "tiebreaker" logic. What clauses should I be using? If anyone had an example of something similar that would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a pretty standard sorting use case. Elasticsearch can sort on multiple fields in a predefined priority order. See documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "sort" : [
        { "num_followers" : {"order" : "desc"}},
        { "num_photos" : "desc" }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "name" : "Customer" }
    }
}
```

Obviously this is just a simple term query -- you may want that to be a keyword search instead based on the wording of your question.